# Overlay image over image in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to add click event to small icon with class 'img'? Also if I move cursor to img element, it will be flashing. How to fix it?

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {
    var element = document.createElement('div');
    element.setAttribute('class', 'img');
    this.parentNode.appendChild(element);
});
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.getElementsByClassName('img')[0]);
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MS8F9/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: @Moosh, vanilla.js, but but I think it does not matter. If you know how to do it with jQuery, please show your version.

Comment: @owl: Why don't you use good old plain `CSS`?! This would be better practice these days. You could also apply animations (e.g. fade) very easily. Using JavaScript for hover effects is like using a sledge-hammer to crack a nut...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need to add inner element into DOM every time, do it via css `:hover` here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MS8F9/2/).

Usually you really don't need to. DOM modification is expensive operation.

Comment: Nice. Thanks. But I'm interested in another version with javascript. 
I do not understand how to do it with js..

Comment: Issue is - when you mouseover inner item, you automatically mouseout outer item. Check [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/MS8F9/3/) in browser console. That's pretty tricky to deal with.